# Prove that A×(B∩C) = (A×B)∩(A×C) by using the set builder notations.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

Prove that A×(B∩C) = (A×B)∩(A×C) by using the set builder notations.

I know how to prove this using containment proof but am lost on how to prove it using set builder notations. What would a proof like this look like?

Can anyone help me with this or give me a clue on how to start with this notation?

Comment: Write out both of them using set builder notation. What does the set $A\times (B\cap C)$ look like? What does the set $(A\times B)\cap (A\times C)$ look like? Compare the two descriptions and see that they are the same. This is what you're asked to do.

Answer (score 1):

By definition, we have
$$
A \times (B \cap C) = \{(x,y) : x \in A \text{ and } y \in B \cap C\} 
\\ = \{(x,y) : x \in A \text{ and } (y \in B \text{ and } y \in  C)\}.
$$
Similarly, 
$$
(A \times B) \cap (A \times C) = \{(x,y) : (x,y) \in A \times B \text{ and } (x,y) \in A \times C\} 
\\ = \{(x,y) : (x \in A \text{ and } y \in B) \text{ and } (x \in A \text{ and }y \in C)\}.
$$
With that established, what we need to show is that the two statements
$$
x \in A \text{ and } (y \in B \text{ and } y \in  C), \quad (x \in A \text{ and } y \in B) \text{ and } (x \in A \text{ and }y \in C)
$$
are logically equivalent.

Comment: wait why is y in the set builder notation? shouldn't it only contain x? Like {x: ...}

Comment: @PatrickPichart depends on your precise definitions.  If you prefer, you can think of "$\{(x,y):\dots$" as being shorthand for "$\{z: z = (x,y) \text{ and}\dots$".

Comment: and also when it asks to prove by set builder notations, would proving  by containment proof be the same? they look the same to me. just without the curly brackets

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "containment proof".  I think you mean that to prove that $S = T$, we show that $S \subseteq T$ and that $T \subseteq S$, is that what you're talking about?

Comment: yes that. is it the same as proof by set builder notation?

Comment: @PatrickPichart They should be very similar, but I wouldn't say "the same".

Comment: The required logical steps are the same.  However, the two proofs have different structures, i.e. different "styles of argument".  In the set builder notation proof, we say "these sets are the same because their descriptions are equivalent".  In the containment proof, we say "the sets are the same because $S$ contains $T$ and $T$ contains $S$". The point of this exercise is at least in part to make sure that you understand what "proving a statement using set builder notation" means. It is important not only to be able to write a proof, but also to talk about a proof.